# BibTeX: Abbreviate first name (aka given name) to 2 or 3 letters (not 1)

Tags: bibtex

BibTeX can abbreviate first names, e.g. change `Smith, John` to `J. Smith`.  In some languages, certain (not all) first names *must* be abbreviated [with more than one letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28orthography%29#Digraphs_versus_letters) (it's not optional as in the case of *Ch.* for *Charles*).  How can I force BibTeX to do this for particular first names?

<sub>*EDIT:*  I encounter this all the time, including for my own name which should be abbreviated *Sz* rather than *S*.  I used to work around the problem by hand editing the reference list in the final version of the paper, but I'd prefer using BibTeX for everything if possible.</sub>

Requested example:

.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{kovacs, smith}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@Book{smith,
  author  = "Peter Smith",
  title   = "Title 1",
  year    = 1980,
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
}

@Book{kovacs,
  author  = "Csaba Kov\'{a}cs",
  title   = "Title 2",
  year    = 1986,
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
}
```

The output I get:

> Text [1, 2].
>
> References
>
> [1] C. Kovács. Title 2. Addison-Wesley, 1986.
>
> [2] P. Smith. Title 1. Addison-Wesley, 1980.

I need to tell bibtex that for *Csaba Kovács* I need to get *Cs. Kovács* in the output, and **not** *C. Kovács*, as this is incorrect.  The document is in English, so this is not a babel-issue.  This applies only to certain author names, and it's because in Hungarian `C` and `Cs` are considered to be distinct units of the alphabet.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Do you require a bibtex style where __all__ first names are to be abbreviated to 2 or 3 letters (instead of 1), or are you looking to put markers on just some names?

Comment: @Mico, only certain names.  The rules of certain languages require that names beginning with certain letter combinations be abbreviated to those combinations (since both S and Sz are considered to be units in the alphabet, a name starting with Sz must always be abbreviated to Sz *in this language*)

Comment: @N.N. see example, please ask about what exactly is not clear in the question

Comment: @Mico, there are no rules that BibTeX can use to determine how to abbreviate the name.  It's too complicated, language dependent, etc.  I am looking for a way to tell it explicitly to abbreviate *this particular name in this particular way*.

Comment: @Szabolcs Excellent, that makes the question much clearer. Would you accept a biblatex solution?

Comment: @N.N. I don't know anything about biblatex.  Any suggestion will be appreciated.  This problem comes up every single time I have to use abbreviated author names, and I usually correct it by hand-editing the final version of the .tex file (and manually inlining bibtex's output).

Comment: @N.N.  Any solution is good if it makes my work easier and most journals accept a tex file using it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just replace the first name in question, say `Csaba`, with `{\relax Cs}aba`.

More generally, place the part of the name that is to be unaffected by the abbreviation *inside* a TeX group, which is a field that's delimited by `{` and `}`, and insert the command `\relax` at the beginning of that group.

Another example of how to make use of this method: To help one's readers distinguish the works authored by "Timothy Jones" and "Thomas Jones", one could set the respective author fields to `"{\relax Tim}othy Jones"` and `"{\relax Th}omas Jones"`.

Here's an MWE that suggests how to deal with four authors whose last name is "Kovács" and first names begin with "C".

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Book{kovacs_ca,
  author  = "Carla Kov{\'a}cs",
  title   = "Title 1",
  year    = 1986,
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
}
@Book{kovacs_ch,
  author  = "{\relax Ch}arles Kov{\'a}cs",
  title   = "Title 2",
  year    = 1987,
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
}
@Book{kovacs_cs,
  author  = "{\relax Cs}aba Kov{\'a}cs",
  title   = "Title 3",
  year    = 1988,
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
}
@Book{kovacs_cy,
  author  = "{\relax Cyr}ill Kov{\'a}cs",
  title   = "Title 4",
  year    = 1989,
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Put

```
\newcommand{\Cs}{Cs}
```

in your `.tex` document and use

```
author="{\Cs}aba Kov{\'{a}}cs"
```

in the `.bib` file.

Comment: Thanks, however I'd prefer a solution which does not require author-specific modifications in the .tex (not .bib) file

Comment: The `\newcommand` bit can go in the `.bib` file: `@preamble{"\newcommand{\Cs}{Cs}"}`; however this can conflict with user defined commands.

Comment: I did not know it could go in the .bib

Comment: To avoid the conflicts, what about `\newcommand{\CsSeriouslyNoOneElseIsUsingThisCommandNameEver}{Cs}`?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This might be a good idea. `:-)` But probably this is more easily solvable with `biblatex`

Answer (score 2):

An automatic solution working with Biblatex and Biber can be found here:
[How to abbreviate first names with multiple letters using Biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297489/how-to-abbreviate-first-names-with-multiple-letters-using-biblatex/297490#297490)

Comment: That should be better a comment, I guess?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422938/35864