# BibTeX: where to write Sir in author's name?

Tags: bibliographies

My bibtex style outputs

> Newton, S. I. Opticks, or a treatise of the reflections, refractions,
>   inflections and colours of light [Text] / Sir Isaac Newton. [S. l.],
>   1730. 382 p. Google Books : XXu4AkRVBBoC.

for the following BibTeX entry

```
@BOOK{IsaacNewton,
author = {Newton, Sir Isaac},
title = {Opticks, or a treatise of the reflections,
refractions, inflections and colours of light},
publisher = {William Innys},
url = {http://books.google.com/books?id=XXu4AkRVBBoC},
year = {1730},
numpages = {382},
eprint = {XXu4AkRVBBoC},
eprinttype = {Google Books},
}
```

How should I change the field

```
author = {Newton, Sir Isaac},
```

obtain something reasonable rather than `Newton, S. I.`? Note that second occurrence of Newton's name (Sir Isaac Newton) is correct.

Incidentally, what would be the correct address: "Sir Isaac" or "Sir Newton"?

Comment: In references you do not need to refer to a persons qualifications nor titles. So I would __not__ add it. If you really want it you can escape the sir by adding it in a group `{Sir}` or `{\relax Sir}`. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26332/bibtex-abbreviate-name-to-2-or-3-letters-not-1

Comment: The `Sir` belongs to the first name. So it would be `Sir Isaac` or `Sir Isaac Newton`, but never `Sir Newton`. More info and references can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following form of the author field will work even if your bibliography style is set to abbreviate first names down to their initials:

```
author = "{\relax Sir I}saac Newton",
```

Comment: Don't you need {\relax Sir I}saac Newton   (which is still simpler than my answer), otherwise abbrv style at least treats the whole brace group as a letter so you get Sir Isaac. with a full stop after the full name,

Comment: You're right! I'll make the change right away. (I had only tested out my answer with a .bst file that abbreviates first names without adding a period (emm, full stop).

Comment: I get a space in front of the sir if I change `firstinits` to `false` (using biblatex v2.9a). `\newcommand\Sir{Sir}` in the preambel and `author = "{\Sir{} I}saac Newton",` in the bib-file seems to be working with both `firstinits` true and false.

Comment: @Mico no, it was a comment on your answer. I have tried this again with biblatex v3.7. For `firstinits=true` (or `giveninits=true` as it is preferred to be called in this version) the output is the same but for `firstinits=false` I get a space in front of the Sir with your solution. I don't know why it behaves that way, but that is what I am observing. Otherwise I would prefer your solution because I do not like this dependency of the bib file on the tex file.

Comment: @jakun - I've posted a [query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378721/5001) to inquire what can be done if `biber` is used as the backend and the option `giveninits=false` is set.

Comment: @jakun - Please see the postings that were provided to answer my new query. It turns out that there's a [very thorough solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378722/5001), which makes use of `biber`'s "extended name format" capabilities, and a [somewhat simpler solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378735/5001), which simply adds an extra brace group around the first-name component of the full name, i.e., which replaces `"{\relax Sir I}saac Newton"` with `"{{\relax Sir I}saac} Newton"`; note the additional pair of curly braces.

Comment: @Mico thank you. That looks better. But, there is yet another issue... please see [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380050/120953)

Answer (score 9):

The title Sir is always used with the first name so never Sir Newton.
usually titles are omitted from bilbliographies I think, but if you want {Sir Isaac} to be get the initial I possibly the simplest is to hide the Sir part in a macro
so mark it up as something like `{\Sir I}saac` with `\Sir` defined to put Sir back on full names and do nothing if just given I (or leave it as Sir I., which is simper).

This has been edited to get the BibTeX braces more correct, it seems to work as given if `\Sir` defined simply as `\newcommand\Sir{Sir }`

Comment: I assume that bibtex DB should be self consistent. That's why I prefer Mico's answer.

Comment: As I said in my comment to Mico;s answer, using \relax is simpler (but I think the brace placement needs adjusting)