# In bibtex/natbib, is there a way to have a shortened name in the citation vs the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

For example, Mary Carter (not her real name) published a book under her married name, Mary Carter van der Merwe.  She subsequently got divorced, and resumed her maiden name professionally.  In the text I would like to cite her book as Carter (2003), even though in the bibliography it will be listed under Carter van der Merwe, M.  Is there an automated way to do this?  I know that I could do it simply by typing Carter and then using the year-only form of the citation.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option? Then you can use the `short` forms for this kind of task.

Comment: If `biblatex` is an option, then this question is a duplicate of [Peerage titles in the author field in BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147935). I don't think this is easy to do in `natbib`.

Comment: Thank, @cfr and Alan.  I am on a project with a short deadline, so hand-coding looks like the way to go, but I will look into switching to biblatex.  I use APA style, which means a forced switch to biber. However, I use Latexian which supports bibtex out of the box, but not biber... so, like most things TeX, there is some assembly required.

Comment: Shall we just close this question as a duplicate then?

Answer (score 5):

I do not agree with the supposed "consensus" you mention in your own answer, i.e., that your objective can't be achieved using the tools provided by the `natbib` package.

Assuming that the entry in question has the citation key "mary2003", you could issue the command

```
\defcitealias{mary2003}{Carter (2003)}
```

up front in your document and use the command `\citetalias{mary2003}` to generate the callout `Carter (2003)`. (The command `\citet{mary2003}`, according to your description, would generate the callout `Carter van der Merwe (2003)`, right?)

As the user guide of the `natbib` package mentions, `\citetalias` functions very much like `\citet`: it can take multiple keys in the argument, it may contain notes, and if you use `hyperref` the callouts will be made into hyperlinks to the entries in the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you! This is a helpful feature of natbib that I had not known about.  Since my citations are program-generated, it will not help me at this point, but I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cfr and @Alan Munn.

The consensus seems to be that this cannot be done in any straightforward way in `natbib`, and that switching to the more up-to-date and powerful `biblatex` is the way to go.