# Bibtex - authors with titles i.e. military rank

Tags: bibtex

Is there support for including an author's title in citations, i.e. their military rank or other title?

Examples include:

`(Blackadder 1917)` in-text and `Blackadder, Captain E. (1917)` in the bibliography.
`(Blackadder 1648)` in -text and `Blackadder, Sir E. (1648)` in the bibliography.

The problem I currently have is that completing the Author field in Bibtex as `Sir Edmund Blackadder` results in:

`Blackadder, S. E. (1648)` in the biblio.

I'm using BibDesk 1.6.2

Edit:
Request for MWE.

Not sure how to, as it's Bibtex, but just insert this into the Author field:

```
{Sir} Edmund Blackadder
```

Or any positioning of the braces. BibDesk gives previews that are replicated in my real file.

Comment: What about enclosing the title in `{}`?

Comment: It still reverts to `Blackadder, S.E.`

Comment: Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: Are you sure you *must* include the title in the bibliography?

Comment: I'm not absolute sure it's a 100% requirement, but it's conventional to use where they're present. I have seen examples in journal articles as well so thought it might be possible.

Comment: Have you checked out the posting [BibTeX: where to write Sir in author's name?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43085/5001) I think you should be in business if you write `author = "{\relax Sir E}dmumd Blackadder",` and `author = "{\relax Captain E}dward Blackadder",`, respectively.

Comment: That's it! Perfect.

Comment: Since the earlier posting and the associated answers appear to address the subject of your new posting, I'm going to propose to close your new posting as a duplicate.

Comment: Good idea, I agree. Don't think I can close it, though.