# Unexpected interaction between biber and a special form of the given-name component of an author's "full" name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Some years ago, [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43085/5001) was posted about how one should enter the honorific "Sir" in the `author` field of a bibliographic entry. (Aside: I suppose the query is also relevant for the use of the honorific "Dame". A second aside: I don't think it's a good idea to provide the honorifics "Sir" and "Dame" in the `author` field. However, let us proceed.)

E.g., consider the case of `Sir Isaac Newton`. If one simply writes

```
author = "Sir Isaac Newton",
```

and one uses a bibliography style that truncates given names, one ends up with either `S. I. Newton` or `Newton, S. I.`. Not good! By convention, "Sir" and "Dame" must *never* be abbreviated. At the time, I provided an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43092/5001) that applies the following "fix" to the `author` field:

```
author = "{\relax Sir I}saac Newton",
```

This fix works just fine with BibTeX. It also works with `biblatex` either if BibTeX is used as the backend or if given names are being truncated (via an option such as `giveninits=true`). However, as has recently been pointed out to me in a comment, there is a problem if (a) `biber` is used as the backend *and* (b) the option `giveninits=false` is set, i.e., if given names are *not* being truncated. Consider the output of a simple two-entry MWE (code posted further below; the author fields are `author = "{\relax Sir I}saac Newton",` and `author = "Zoe Zerlina Zwicky",`, respectively.):

[image]

Note the whitespace immediately before "Sir". The MWE was compiled with MacTeX2017, `biblatex` 3.7 and `biber` 2.7. FWIW, here are the two `given` fields created by `biber` (copied and pasted from `\jobname.bbl`):

```
given={{\relax\bibnamedelimb Sir\bibnamedelimb I}saac},
given={Zoe\bibnamedelima Zerlina},
```

Observe that `biber` has inserted `\bibnamedelimb` between `\relax` and `Sir`. The presence of this macro is responsible for the insertion of the unwanted bit of whitespace.

**Question**: Is there an option that can/must be set to eliminate either the first instance of `\bibnamedelimb` or the entire string `\relax\bibnamedelimb` from the `given` field? Alternatively, is this a bug in `biber` (which will eventually be fixed)?

---

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@misc{SIN, author = "{\relax Sir I}saac Newton", title = "Opticks", year = 1730, note = "Fourth edition"}
@misc{ZZZ, author = "Zoe Zerlina Zwicky", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[giveninits=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Biber you can use the 'extended name format'. There you can specify the abbreviated form of a name part explicitly if you don't like default.

You would use

```
author  = {family={Newton}, given={Sir Isaac}, given-i={Sir I}},
```

And would get

> Sir Isaac Newton

in full, or

> Sir I. Newton

in abbreviated form.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{IsaacNewton,
  author  = {family={Newton}, given={Sir Isaac}, given-i={Sir I}},
  title   = {Opticks},
  year    = 1730,
  edition = {4},
}
@misc{xyz,
  author = {Zoe Zwicky},
  title  = {Thoughts},
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[giveninits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. ;-) Many thanks for this quick and thorough answer. I take it that the `\relax` "trick" -- which works fine in many BibTeX cases -- simply shouldn't be used with `biber`. Just out of curiosity: Would you know of a way to suppress the insertion of `\bibnamedelimb` immediately after `\relax` (and before "Sir")? Or is it the case that `biber` detokenizes (or otherwise treats) the elements of the `author` field prior to processing and thus never has a chance to notice that `\relax` might be "special"?

Comment: @Mico I would say so, yes. Biber's parsing is subtly different in some cases (especially when it comes to braces, not only in name fields, also in title fields - where then the sentence casing macro comes in). I'm not sure how Biber exactly inserts `\bibnamedelimb`, so I don't know a trick to not make it insert it after `\relax`. But I'm quite sure that `\bibnamedelimb` is inserted at a stage where Biber knows few things if any about TeX commands. If you think that is worth a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: Note that "Sir I. Newton" is very bad form. Knights are known by their given names, not their surnames so, in a situation where you'd abbreviate me to "Mr Richerby", Newton would be "Sir Isaac".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Absolutely. It was one of the premises of the question to ignore the unreasonableness of the request.

Answer (score 5):

Prompted by comments by @moewe below his [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378722/5001) -- and especially by the allusion to how `biber` treats material in so-called "brace groups" (any material encased in an extra pair of curly braces) -- I've come up with another working solution. It's not as thorough as the one given by @moewe, but it's quite simple, in that it requires the use of just one extra brace group to help `biber` figure out what's the given-name component of the full name. Specifically, all that needs to be done is to replace

```
author = "{\relax Sir I}saac Newton",
```

with

```
author = "{{\relax Sir I}saac} Newton",
```

With the extra brace group in place, `biber` does not get around to inserting a `\bibnamedelimb` directive either between `\relax` and `Sir` or between "Sir" and the Initial "I". As a result, ordinary interword spaces get inserted. I suppose this could cause a new issue if, for some reason, `\bibnamedelimb` were to be set to something that's materially different from `\space`; fortunately, this doesn't appear to be the case here.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@misc{SIN0, 
  author = "{\relax Sir I}saac Newton", 
  title  = "Opticks", note = "Not correct"
}
@misc{SIN1,
  author = {family={Newton}, given={Sir Isaac}, given-i={Sir I}},
  title  = {Opticks}, note = "Correct"
}
@misc{SIN2, 
  author = "{{\relax Sir I}saac} Newton", 
  title  = "Opticks", note = "Also correct"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[giveninits=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1) As far as I can tell this will not cause a problem with `\bibnamedelimb` at all. The only thing that might be a bit meh is that the first name now is in another group, I'm nor sure if that can have adverse effects (for line breaking or kerning).