# Hyphen in title of author (using biblatex & biber with giveninits=true)

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is a follow up of [Mico's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378721/120953) on how to specify an author's title with `giveninits=true`. There two answers have been found which work for titles which do not include a hyphen.

Now, let us consider the title "Dr.-Ing.".
With both answers I get an additional dot in front of the hyphen:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@unpublished{tet-skript-moewe,
    author = {family={Schuhmann}, given={Prof. Dr.-Ing. Rolf}, given-i={Prof. Dr.-Ing. R}},
    title  = {Skriptum zu den {V}orlesungen 
              {T}heoretische {E}lektrotechnik {I} und {II}},
    date   = {2013-12-17},
    note   = {moewe's answer}
}
@unpublished{tet-skript-mico,
    author = {{{\relax Prof. Dr.-Ing. R}olf} Schuhmann},
    title  = {Skriptum zu den {V}orlesungen 
              {T}heoretische {E}lektrotechnik {I} und {II}},
    date   = {2013-12-17},
    note   = {Mico's answer}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

I am aware of one work around which I will post as an answer.
However, I do not like it because it involves defining custom commands and thus creating a dependency of the bib file on the tex file.

Does someone know a better solution?

Comment: It definitely doesn't seem right that `biber` (a) modifies the *interior* of the `given-i` field in the first entry and (b) essentially ignores the `\relax` instruction in the second entry.

Comment: Note that it is highly unusual to include academic titles and degrees in a bibliography. I have never seen a scientific work doing it and I would be hard pressed to find a popular science work that includes titles (but I can't guarantee that I have not seen one). Even in Germany you would not include the degree.

Comment: @Mico There is a rationale for modifying the interior of `given-i`. Names such as 'Hans-Georg' would be `H-G` and Biber would then insert `\bibinithyphendelim` also before the `-`.

Comment: @moewe, I can agree with you that academic degrees are unusual there, but I think this is of little relevance, given that the behavior would be the same for a regular compound name. Shouldn't Biber be robust enough to give correct results if someone would give `given-i = {H.-D.}` instead in the field?

Comment: @gusbrs You could expect that, yes. I'm not sure about the inner workings of Biber here, but I can see why things are like they are now. The feature developed over time and the present state is a direct consequence of things that were necessary in the past. If you think that there should be a way to get `gievn-i` exactly without interference you can submit a feature request for Biber (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues).

Comment: @moewe, I'm trying to explore the issue and to understand. But I think I ought to be humble on feature requests. Still much to learn. BTW, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know why it works, but you can remove the dot in `Dr-Ing.`, and the added one will be there to obtain the desired results:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@unpublished{tet-skript-moewe,
    author = {family={Schuhmann}, given={Prof. Dr.-Ing. Rolf}, given-i={Prof. Dr-Ing. R}},
    title  = {Skriptum zu den {V}orlesungen 
              {T}heoretische {E}lektrotechnik {I} und {II}},
    date   = {2013-12-17},
    note   = {moewe's answer}
}
@unpublished{tet-skript-mico,
    author = {{{\relax Prof. Dr-Ing. R}olf} Schuhmann},
    title  = {Skriptum zu den {V}orlesungen 
              {T}heoretische {E}lektrotechnik {I} und {II}},
    date   = {2013-12-17},
    note   = {Mico's answer}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It works for both Mico's and moewe's solutions.

[image]

Comment: True, this will still leave you with a dependency between the bib file and the tex file, for if you abandon the `giveninits=true` option, you will be missing the dot.

Comment: @moewe, do you think this is desired behavior? Is "Prof. Dr.-Ing." stretching the purpose of `given` name? Or is there an `\isdot` or alike missing somewhere in the case of "compound names"?

Comment: It is highly unusual to include academic titles in the bibliography and 'Prof. Dr.-Ing.' does not quite work like a first name. Biber inserts `\bibinithyphendelim` before a hyphen when it does initials to get names like 'Hans-Dieter' right, that would be `given-i = {H-D}` and then `H\bibinithyphendelim G\bibinitperiod`. Here the same happens, `\bibinithyphendelim` is inserted before the hyphen. That's why hiding it in a command helps, the insertion is done by Biber who does not expand your TeX commands.

Comment: @jakun, given moewe's comments on what Biber expects in `given-i` and how it works I believe this might be your best bet. Plus, contrary to my initial impression, you can achieve independence of tex and bib files (in the sense of not depending on your defined commands and also not depending on the option given to `giveninits`, leading to correct results for `true` or (default) `false`). It is enough that (in moewe's solution) you supply the dot in `Dr.` for `given` and omit it for `given-i`. I changed the answer's code accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Putting the hyphen in a command avoids the insertion of an additional dot.

<s>I am assuming that this works because the hyphen's catcode is here fixed to other and can not be made active.</s> According to moewe's comment on [gusbrs' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380056/120953) this works because "the insertion is done by Biber who does not expand your TeX commands".

I am not sure why those curley braces around the commands are needed but without them I am getting an error.

The position of those braces is based on an [answer by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43092/120953).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@unpublished{tet-skript,
    author = {{\Prof{} \DrIng{} R}olf Schuhmann},
    title  = {Skriptum zu den {V}orlesungen 
              {T}heoretische {E}lektrotechnik {I} und {II}},
    date   = {2013-12-17},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\newcommand{\DrIng}{Dr.-Ing.\@}
\newcommand{\Prof}{Prof.\@}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]