# Is is possible to not abbreviate the author name of only one reference in my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, acronyms, ieeetran

I am using the `IEEEtran.bst` file for my bibliography (as follows):

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,biblio}
```

and it works as desired in all but one case. I have one entry where the 'author' is "World Health Organization and others", which gets abbreviated as "W. H. Organization et al.". Obviously, this is not what I want.

Is there a way I can use `IEEEabrv`, but make an exception for this one entry?

Please note that I am obliged to use this style (not natbib or anything else) due to the conference submission guidelines.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your problem is not caused by `IEEEabrv.bib`, which simply contains the abbreviated names of IEEE journals; it is rather caused by the style `IEEEtran.bst`, which is programmed to abbreviate author names.

According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26332/bibtex-abbreviate-name-to-2-or-3-letters-not-1/26347#26347), maybe you could write your author as

`author = {{\relax World Health Organization} and others}`

Comment: If you do this, you still get a period after "World Health Organization". Is there a way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 26):

The `\relax` solution didn't work for me, but putting the author in double brackets like this got rid of the problem:

```
author = {{The Agda Team}}
```

Comment: Using `author = "{The Agda Team}"` will also work.

Comment: Same here! Thanks!