# how to force Bibtex to treat two letters as one for author initials?

Tags: bibtex

I have a citation that is transliterated from Russian Cyrillic.

```
@book{kondratyev_radiation_1969,
    address = {New York},
    series = {International geophysics series},
    title = {Radiation in the atmosphere},
    volume = {12},
    publisher = {Academic Press},
    author = {Kondratyev, K. Ya.},
    year = {1969},
    keywords = {Atmosphere, Solar radiation, Transport theory},
}
```

This means that the authors second initial is 'Ya' yet when using bibtex the a gets cut off.

[image: screen shot of bibliography entry]

I even tried this with no success:

```
@book{kondratyev_radiation_1969,
    address = {New York},
    series = {International geophysics series},
    title = {Radiation in the atmosphere},
    volume = {12},
    publisher = {Academic Press},
    author = {Kondratyev, K. {Ya}.},
    year = {1969},
    keywords = {Atmosphere, Solar radiation, Transport theory},
}
```

Does anyone know how to force bibtex to treat the two letters Ya as one?

Comment: `author = {Kondratyev, K. {\relax Ya}.},`? (Haven't checked)

Comment: What bibliography style are you using? That's important, because with `plain` I get “Ya.”.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26332/35864

Comment: @egreg `abbrv` gives initials but a different general output from the one shown in the screenshot (which in turn can't come from the `.bib` item posted). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it is fair to assume that if the OP indeed uses BibTeX it does not really matter which abbreviated style is used since they all rely on the same BibTeX function.